# how to get Table element from a Div that has a Heading tag with a known text - using selenium and java

Tags: selenium

```
            <h3>Movers and Shakers</h3>
            <p>

                <strong>Strategy Hint 1:</strong><br>
                <strong>Strategy Hint 2:</strong><br>

            </p>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>ExternalId</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Price cents</td>
                    <td>Brand</td>
                  <tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>123</td>
                    <td>Draw</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Ciko</td>
                  <tr>
```

---

Now, the know text in the h3 tag is 'Movers and Shakers'. The table and h3 are in a Div tag. Now, how do I get the table for this specific div that has that specific known text('Movers and Shakers').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of `xpath`, use following code to return the `DIV` element that contains a heading `H3` with the text `Movers and Shakers`:

```
WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[h3[text()='Movers and Shakers']]"));
```

Ant then, find the table inside this `div` web-element:

```
WebElement table = div.findElement(By.xpath(".//table"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the table element you want:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[h3[contains(.,'Movers and Shakers')]]")).findElement(By.tagName("table"));
```

Answer (score 0):

this short line worked

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Movers and Shakers')]/following-sibling::table"));
```